# MapKit's .convert() function is not working on SwiftUI macOS, I get a SIGABRT error when I run it

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I get an error when I try to run the new `.convert()` function with MapKit on macOS. The code I am using is below. When I run this code on the iOS simulator, it runs without any problems. But when I try this on macOS, I get a `SIGABRT` error. I am running this on Xcode 15 beta 7.

```
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        MapReader { reader in
            Map {
                if let location {
                    Marker("(\(location.latitude), \(location.longitude))", coordinate: location)
                }
            }
            .onTapGesture { coords in
                location = reader.convert(coords, from: .local) // This is what is causing the error.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The console shows this after I run it:

```
dyld[35102]: Symbol not found: _$s15_MapKit_SwiftUI0A5ProxyV7convert_4fromSo22CLLocationCoordinate2DVSgSo7CGPointV_xt0cD023CoordinateSpaceProtocolRzlF
  Referenced from: <1B995F7F-26B0-3877-A3D8-887D05F7164E> /Users/mohalibou/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Testlol-dqropkwgughsodffunzdvseijasi/Build/Products/Debug/Testlol.app/Contents/MacOS/Testlol
  Expected in:     <67E0E989-BDE1-384E-A80C-9297D2186069> /System/Library/Frameworks/_MapKit_SwiftUI.framework/Versions/A/_MapKit_SwiftUI
```

Comment: Your code works well for me in my tests, no errors, on MacOS 14, Xcode 15, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews), macCatalyst and macOS.
 It could be different on older systems.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Damn, in that case I have no idea what's wrong. I tried running this code on fresh iOS and macOS projects, but for some reason, it just refuses to work for macOS...

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Which beta version of Xcode 15 were you using?

Comment: I'm using Xcode Version 15.0 beta 7. Just updated to Xcode Version 15.0 beta 7 (15A5229h) and macOS Sonoma Version 14.0 Beta (23A5328b)